# How can I edit/load JSON file in Python

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I've looked at several questions and I could not get it working! The thing I'm trying to edit JSON file when my bot (discord bot) is being joined to new guild or is leaving guild!

My default JSON file look like this:

```
{
  "guilds": {

  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add another array where will be listed guild-id and another config for specific servers. I tried this and it did not worked!

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f);

    data["guilds"][guild.id] = {
        "join-message": "Welcome {member} to {server-name}! We hope you enjoy!"
    }

    with open('data.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(f,data);
```

So I want the JSON file looks like this when new guilds are being added:

```
{
  "guilds": {
      {
        "guild-id": 418718584455,
        "join-message": "Welcome to blablabla"
      },
  }
}
```

and I want this happen always when bot is being joined when bot is leaving I will loop trough list of guilds and find the right and then delete it!

This seem to be not working, I get no error from it and file isnt being edited!

If anyone know how could achieve that please reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data["guilds"].append(({"guild-id": guild.id,
                 "join-message": "Welcome {member} to {server-name}! We hope 
                  you enjoy!"
                 }))

    with open('data.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(data ,f);
```

Comment: Could I ask about deleting this new array?

Comment: delete with guild id ??

Answer (score 0):

Should it be this in the final line?

```
import json

with open('data.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f) # <<--- this one is inverted
```

Comment: As I said I was working with tutorials so this can be wrong, I have no idea of doing this type thing

Comment: Is it the answer? Please try ;)

Comment: What? This line I added because in tutorials were added when they were writing files so I don't know

Comment: You may check this post on how json package is used for the dump() function.
https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/

Comment: @hongkail So append function should do the trick I'm looking for?

Comment: @Pixeluted No need to append new function. You may modify this line json.dump(data, f) on your existing code json.dump(f, data)